# html not loading jquery? (dynamic content loading)

Tags: jquery, html

For the site I'm building, I'm trying to dynamically load content from other html files into the index.html (so when you click a nav link it won't load a whole new page, it will just load in content from a different html file). I've been told the best way to do this is using jquery.

I've included the jquery library up in my page head, and I'm able to call the .js file where the code will live (it successfully loaded an alert('boo')), but none of the content within the jquery functions will load. Here's the code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"</script>
<script src='js/script.js'></script>
```

and then in the scrpt.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
    $('#content').load('content/index.html');
});
```

Comment: You know you don't close your first script tag, right?  Does it make any difference if you do?  Can you provide **any** debugging information at all, or are we to guess?  What's in your network tab?  See an HTTP request?  Anything in the console?

Comment: Are you loading jQuery as well as jQuery UI?

Comment: submit the  edited code you  have  not close the script tag for first one

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

...
<div id="content"> </div>
...

<script>
    $(document).ready(function()    {
        $('#content').load('content/index.html');
    });
</script>
```

be sure to not forget or mistake the #content and be sure 'content/index.html' can be reach from the actual page.
No reason it is not working

EDIT: Be sure to not forget load **jquery** since jquery != jquery ui

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding HTTP to your call to jquery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"</script>
```

Also you are missing a closing > on your script tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not the solution.  URLs with `//` are valid, and will use whatever the current protocol is.

Comment: @Brad: It may very well be the solution if OP isn't using a webserver and is opening the HTML files directly with his browser.

Comment: I have had issues in the past when I omitted the http as it was trying to go to: mydomain.com//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js, which I think might depend on settings off the webserver, however I am not sure

Comment: @JanR, I don't believe you.  You probably had something inserting your hostname and base path in before your links.  I guarantee you that if you use `//` at the beginning of a URL in HTML, it will work fine.

Comment: Could be, in my case adding the http was the solution :)

Comment: What you describe would happen if you just had `/ajax...` instead of `//ajax...`. The URL spec is very clear that `//` precedes a hostname and `/` precedes a pathname, and if the method is omitted it defaults to whatever method was used to load the current page. If you saw any other behavior, it was an extremely brokne browser.